# wordpress json rest API to get custom field data

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I am currently using the [JSON REST API (WP API)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) plug-in to get my post and page data.

I have noticed that none of my custom field data is returned in the json, and looking at the routes, i don't think i can obtain these.

Any ideas via the current plug-in, or how I can accomplish this otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 'advanced custom fields' - until something more official is decided, you can use this plugin:  https://github.com/times/acf-to-wp-api (and now on the shelf in standard wp plugin area too.)

It will include the custom fields under `acf: [],` in your json structure.

Comment: acf array is always empty, can you please guide.

Comment: @Riz - you'll have to set the custom post types to 'show in json' or something. Check that, will yah.

Answer (score 1):

To grab a custom field value using native WP functions only, add the following to your functions.php

```
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
  $_data = $data->data;
  $_data[$field] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_field_key', true );
  $data->data = $_data;
  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Replace `'my_custom_field_key'` with your custom field key name.

For multiple fields:

```
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
  $_data = $data->data;
  // My custom fields that I want to include in the WP API v2 responce
  $fields = ['writer', 'publisher', 'year', 'youtube_link'];

  foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    $_data[$field] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field, true );
  }

  $data->data = $_data;
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: In the theme functions.php? Then what URL to display?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Combined with http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/using-the-client I got the fields as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create this file contain following code in

> wp-content\themes\name\inc\functions

```
   <?php
        if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

        /*
         * init function
         */
        if ( ! function_exists( 'mnu_rest_init' ) ) {
                  function mnu_rest_init() {       
                      register_rest_route( 'guider/v1', '/booking', array(
                      'methods' => 'GET',
                      'callback' => 'handle_get_all',
                      'permission_callback' => function () {
                       return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
                    }
                  ) );
                register_rest_route( 'guider/v1', '/booking', array(
                      'methods' => 'POST',
                      'callback' => 'handle_post_booking',
                      'permission_callback' => function () {
                       return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
                    }
                  ) );
          }
        }

    //GET QUERY PARMS
    function handle_get_all( $request_data) {
        $parameters = $request_data->get_params();
         $userId = $parameters["Id"];
         global $wpdb;
         $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_trav_tour_bookings` WHERE `user_id` = $userId";
         $list = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        return $list;
    }

    // GET BODY PARMS
    function handle_post_booking( $request_data) {
        $parameters = $request_data->get_body();
        $params = json_decode( $parameters , true );
       //  $userId = $parameters["Id"];
        // global $wpdb;
        // $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_trav_tour_bookings` WHERE `user_id` = $userId";
        // $list = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        return $params ;
    }
```

then you need to add

```
//actions
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'mnu_rest_init');
```

to your main.php in

> wp-content\themes\name\inc\functions

to do that you need to require this file to main.php

```
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/filename.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the response and add custom fields to the JSON. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields in my example but you can just add any key/value-pairs to the data object before returning it.

```
// In functions.php
function modify_rest_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
  if (is_admin()) {
    return $data;
  }

  $data->my_favorite_data = get_field('my_custom_field', $post->ID);
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'modify_rest_post', 10, 3 );
```